# How should I configure '.htaccess' to redirect this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I have 3 domains on Hostinger, namely

```
'puxir.com' | for hosting
'puxir.org' >> redirect to 'puxir.com'
'puxir.net' >> redirect to 'puxir.com'
```

And 2 subdomains on the website:

```
m.puxir.com > for Mautic
w.puxir.com > for Drupal
```

Currently I am working with 3 '.htaccess' files:

```
[ public_html/.htaccess ]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m|w)\. [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://w.puxir.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

[ public_html/m/.htaccess ]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://m.puxir.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

[ public_html/w/.htaccess ]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://w.puxir.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But right now I'm stuck trying to get some redirections just work on Apache.
Examples:

```
(R1) http://www.puxir.org >> https://w.puxir.com/
[PASS!]

(R2) http://www.puxir.net >> https://w.puxir.com/
[PASS!]

(R3) http://www.puxir.com >> https://w.puxir.com/
[FAIL!]

(Mind the http/https negotiations above...)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please give us what kind of error, and erorr message on browser or web log file.

Comment: "403 - Forbidden: Access to this resource on the server is denied!"

Answer (score 0):

You could test this:

```
#[ public_html/.htaccess ]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(m|w)\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://w.puxir.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The [Space] in [NC, OR] must be suppressed.

Comment: "403 - Forbidden: Access to this resource on the server is denied!", even after changes (thx for answer)

Comment: You redirect to w.puxir.com, why not www ? w might not be defined in your dns server.